# Which one is correct - You better ask James or better you ask James?

Tags: phrase-requests, questions, you-all

"You better ask James" or "better you ask James" which one is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, but with subtly different meanings. What is supposed to be `better`, the action of asking James, or the whole act of you asking James?

Comment: the action of asking James.

Comment: The second has an implicit `It is` and a `that`, as in `It is better that you ask James`. It keeps `you ask James` as a single entity undivided entity. The first one doesn't necessarily include `You` in the entity which is called `better`. If this is the meaning that you want to convey, then use the first. Maybe I shouldn't have said as much as different meanings, but instead the same meaning with different flavors.

Comment: To me (British English speaker) 'You better...' is very informal; the correct version would be 'You had better ask James.'

Answer (score 1):

They mean subtly different things.

*"You better ask James"* simply means *"You should ask James"*.

*"Better you ask James"* means *"It would be better if you asked James"*.  It implies that someone else is being asked, eg "instead of me".  It's like saying *"You've asked the wrong person - James is a better person to ask."*

Some context examples:
"Can I leave early today?" - "You better ask James".  James here could be the boss.  Speaker B is saying "You need to ask James, since he can make that decision".

"What time is James leaving today?" "Better you ask James".  Here, speaker B is saying "How am I supposed to know?  Ask James."